# How to setup timezone in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, timezone

I'm using Symfony and I would like to set specific timezone to my application. I can't use php.ini, is there a way to do it inside Symfony?

Answer (score 1):

You can set it via pure PHP:

```
date_default_timezone_set(YOUR_TIME_ZONE_HERE);
```

If you want it to be set in the very early moment you should place this code in your front-controller at `app.php` (or `app_dev.php`/`app_test.php`).